# Multi class support vector machine classifier with numpy overflow

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning

Here's a grammatically corrected version of your message:

I am developing a multi-class classifier with NumPy and have created the main logic to calculate the gradient of MSVM and the forward pass. However, when I run my code, I encounter an overflow error. I understand that this is usually caused by the result of the calculation exceeding the capacity of the machine due to ineffective hyperparameters. However, I suspect that there may be something else going wrong because the loss does not seem to be decreasing.

Following my logic, I encountered an overflow error in the **softmax_forward()** function when using the exponential function, even after tuning the hyperparameters (learning rate, regularization rate, batch size, etc.)

below is my linear regression section code

```
class Linear_v2:
    def __init__(self, input_size=1, hidden_size=1):
        # Initialize weights and biases
        self.W = np.random.randn(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.b = np.zeros(hidden_size)
        
        # Store input size and hidden size
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        
    def forward(self, x):
        # Calculate linear transformation
        self.x = x
        out = np.dot(x, self.W) + self.b
        
        return out
    
    def backward(self, dout, lr, lamb=0):
        # Calculate gradients for weights and biases    
        dW = np.dot(self.x.T, dout)
        db = np.sum(dout, axis=0)
        
        # Update weights and biases
        self.W -= lr * (dW + lamb*self.W)
        self.b -= lr * db
        
        # Calculate gradients for input
        # print(dout.shape, self.W.T.shape)
        dx = np.dot(dout, self.W.T)
        
        return dx
```

and the code located below is softmax based MSVM algorithm.

```
class Softmax_with_MSVM:
    def __init__(self):
        # softmax
        self.softmax_out = None
        self.softmax_x = None
        # MSVM
        self.MSVM_out = None

    def softmax_forward(self, x):
        self.softmax_x = x
        # subtracting the maximum value for numerical stability
        exp_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True))
        self.softmax_out = exp_x / np.sum(exp_x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        return self.softmax_out

    def forward(self, x, target, reg=0.1):
        self.target = target
        self.MSVM_out = self.softmax_forward(x)
        scores = np.dot(x, self.MSVM_out.T)
        correct_scores = scores[np.arange(x.shape[0]), target.flatten()]
        margins = np.maximum(0, scores - correct_scores.reshape(-1, 1) + 1)
        margins[np.arange(x.shape[0]), target.flatten()] = 0
        loss = np.sum(margins)
        loss /= x.shape[0]
        loss += 0.5 * reg * np.sum(self.MSVM_out ** 2)
        self.pred = (scores >= np.max(scores, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)).astype(float)
        return loss

    def backward(self, lr=1e-3):
        batch_size = self.pred.shape[0]

        # derivative of cross-entropy loss w.r.t. softmax output
        dL_dsoftmax = self.MSVM_out - self.target

        # gradient of softmax layer
        dsoftmax_dMSVMx = (self.softmax_out * (1 - self.softmax_out))
        dL_dMSVMx = dL_dsoftmax * dsoftmax_dMSVMx

        # gradient of MSVM
        zero_mask = (dL_dsoftmax == 0) | (self.MSVM_out == 0)
        dL_dMSVMx = np.where(zero_mask, 0, -dL_dMSVMx)
        dMSVMx_dw = np.dot(dL_dMSVMx.T, self.pred) / batch_size

        # update weights
        self.MSVM_out -= (lr * dMSVMx_dw).T
        return dL_dMSVMx
```

the last thing is train module

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def train_MSVM(config, train_img=train_img, train_label=train_label):
    lr, num_epoch, batch_size = config['learning_rate'], config['num_epoch'], config['batch_size']
    print_loss_interval = 20
    
    layer1 = Linear_v2(784, 100)
    activation_function = config['activation_function']
    layer2 = Linear_v2(100, 10)
    softmax_with_MSVM = Softmax_with_MSVM()
    
    for iter in range(num_epoch):
        # forward
        num_data = len(train_img)
        num_batch = num_data // batch_size
        if num_data % batch_size != 0:
            num_batch += 1

        epoch_loss = 0

        for batch_idx in range(num_batch):
            start_idx = batch_idx * batch_size
            end_idx = min(num_data, (batch_idx + 1) * batch_size)

            batch_img = train_img[start_idx:end_idx]
            batch_label = train_label[start_idx:end_idx]

            x = layer1.forward(batch_img)
            x = activation_function.forward(x)
            x = layer2.forward(x)
            preds = softmax_with_MSVM.softmax_forward(x)
            
            loss = softmax_with_MSVM.forward(preds, batch_label, config['reg'])
            batch_loss = loss.sum() / len(preds)
            epoch_loss += batch_loss

            # backward
            dL = softmax_with_MSVM.backward()
            dL = layer2.backward(dL, lr)
            dL = activation_function.backward(dL)
            dL = layer1.backward(dL, lr)

        avg_loss = epoch_loss / num_batch
        print(avg_loss)

        if iter == 0 or (iter + 1) % print_loss_interval == 0:
            print("[epoch %d / %d] average loss : %f" % (iter + 1, num_epoch, avg_loss))

    model = OrderedDict()
    model['layer1'] = layer1
    model['activation_function'] = activation_function
    model['layer2'] = layer2
    model['softmax_with_MSVM'] = softmax_with_MSVM
    
    return model
```